# Как в modx revo скрывать tv параметр при условии отмеченного checkbox?

Tags: modx, revo

Сделал шаблон для товаров и туда поместил tv параметры Gender(пол), garmentBoy(одежда для мальчиков), garmentGirl(одежда для девочек), как в админке на revo сделать так что если я устанавливаю в tv  Gender  флажок на чекбокс Девочка то при этом скрывался бы tv garmentBoy, ведь создавать несколько шаблонов из за одного параметра тоже не всегда удобно особенно если это будет делать пользователь которому не хочется разбираться как создовать товары как выбирать шаблоны зачем и почему. Предложите хотя бы куда копать, кто встречал подобные вещи?![image]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте категорию например Нужное
И перенесите все TV которые нужно заполнять туда
Тогда пользователь будет выбирать эту категорию и не тыкать другие TV